# What is the equivalent of wp_set_password function in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, account

I found out that I can customize the `wp_set_password` function and put my code in it. But it's only executed when a user register through `/wp-login.php`.

This was my code:

```
function wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) {
    // Keep original WP code
    global $wpdb;

    $hash = wp_hash_password( $password );
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->users,
        array(
            'user_pass'           => $hash,
            'user_activation_key' => '',
        ),
        array( 'ID' => $user_id )
    );

    wp_cache_delete( $user_id, 'users' );

    // and now add your own
    $custom_hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', $custom_hash);
}
```

However I have installed WooCommerce and all three main tasks regarding **password** are:

- Registration,
- Profile update,
- Password reset.

So this code doesn't help me with that and I've searched for a similar function in WooCommerce, but I couldn't find it. Is there anyway that I can edit WooCommerce like this in my custom plugin and what is the function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should **always avoid to overwrite any core file**, as you will loose your changes when WordPress will be updated and you can make big trouble in this related sensible processes.

In Woocommerce the equivalent of WordPress [`wp_set_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_password/) is the [`WC_Customer`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html) [`set_password()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html#_set_password) method.

To get it pluggable you can use `[WC_Customer_Data_Store][4]` Class **related hooks** located in [`update()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#163-185) method:

- On user creation, for "User registration", use `woocommerce_new_customer` action hook .
- On user update events, use `woocommerce_update_customer` action hook
- On "User registration" (user creation), you can use `woocommerce_new_customer` action hook
- When changing/saving the password on My account > Account details section, you can use `woocommerce_save_account_details` action hook too.
- When the password get reseted you can use `woocommerce_customer_reset_passwor` action hook.

---

Example usage of [`WC_Customer`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html) [`set_password()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html#_set_password) method:

```
// Get the WC_Customer instance object from the user ID
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

// Set password
$customer->set_password( $password );

// Save to database and sync
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Hello Luis thanks for your answer, is the $password using in this code is raw format ? I dont want to create a WooCommerce customer, I want store password during registration in an extra field in usermeta table, how can I do this with this method without touching the core WooCommerce ?
Im writing everything in my own plugin